# User not allowed because shell ls does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am getting Access Denied error while connecting SSH server running Ubuntu inside Virtual-Box.

> Access Denied

Whine inside the OS Terminal  `>sudo systemctl status ssh`  give the follwing line in output :

```
User not allowed because shell ls does not exist
```

Comment: >ssh localhost  getting Permission denied, please try again after entering password

Comment: please check following [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872297/sshd-user-username-not-allowed-because-shell-zsh-does-not-exist) maybe it also works for you

Comment: I dont understand the shell ls or shell zsh here